# Variance of the stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, variance

I am asked to find $Var(aW_t+b\int_0^tf(s)W_sds)$. This is what I did until now:

\begin{align*} &\mathbb{E}\left(a^2W_t^2+2abW_t\int_0^tf(s)W_sds+b^2\left[\int_0^tf(s)W_s \, ds\right]^2 \right) \\&=a^2t+2ab\int_0^tf(s)\mathbb{E}(W_t,W_s)ds+b^2\mathbb{E}\left(\left[\int_0^tf(s)W_s \, ds \right]^2 \right) \\ &=a^2t+2ab\int_0^tf(s)sds+b^2\mathbb{E}\left(\left[\int_0^tf(s)W_s \, ds \right]^2 \right) \end{align*}

but I do not know if I am doing it correctly and how to calculate the last expectation.

Comment: Write $$\left( \int_0^t f(s) W_s \, ds \right)^2 = \int_0^t \int_0^t f(s) W_s f(u) W_u \, ds \, du$$ and apply Fubini's theorem

Comment: Why not? You just need to compute $\mathbb{E}(W_s W_u)$

Comment: I got it thank you!